# perl program to parse three tokens in arbitary order

Tags: perl, parsing

I need to parse a buillog in which three tokens (or keywords) that come in any arbitary order. Please help.

```
HBStartArchiverList  - Command indicates the start of addition of list of objects at command HBAddObjectToArchiverList , HBFinishArchiverList indicates the completion of addition. HBAddObjectToArchiverList may appear one or more between start and finish.




     -- pattern1 -- easy to parse ------------
   HBStartArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\a.txt
   HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\a.txt
   HBFinishArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\a.txt
   ------------------------------------------

   -- pattern2 -- easy to parse ------------
   HBStartArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\b.txt
   HBAddObjectToArchiverList  E:\AA\BB\CC\b.txt
   HBAddObjectToArchiverList  E:\AA\BB\CC\b.txt
   HBAddObjectToArchiverList  E:\AA\BB\CC\b.txt
   HBAddObjectToArchiverList  E:\AA\BB\CC\b.txt
   HBFinishArchiverList  E:\AA\BB\CC\b.txt
   --------------------------------------------

 ----pattern3 -----Difficult to parse---
     HBStartArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\c.txt
     HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\c.txt
     HBStartArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\d.txt
     HBFinishArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\c.txt
     HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\d.txt
     HBFinishArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\d.txt
  ---------------------------------------
pattern3 is difficult because i expect c.txt to finish, but d.txt start appears before finish of c.txt.



 -----pattern4 -----Difficult to parse----
 HBStartArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\e.txt
 HBStartArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\f.txt
 HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\e.txt
 HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\f.txt
 HBFinishArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\e.txt
 HBFinishArchiverList E:\AA\BB\CC\f.txt
 -----------------------------------------**
```

pattern4 is difficult start of e.txt and f.txt comes one after the other.

**>  ----

> ```
> Line 16064: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser_common.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 16069: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser_common.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 16079: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser_common.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 16098: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\imp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser_common.a 
>   Line 17954: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 17959: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 17964: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 17969: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 17974: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 17986: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 17991: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 18003: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 18012: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\imp\libimp_ntg5_onlineservices_browser.a
>
>   Line 18024: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdmsconfig.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18029: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdmsconfig.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18034: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdmsconfig.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18043: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\imp\libdmsconfig.a
>
>   Line 18108: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginsCommonS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18113: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libntg5_browser_audiosource_dsi.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18118: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginsCommonS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18123: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libntg5_browser_audiosource_dsi.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18128: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libntg5_browser_audiosource_dsi.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18133: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginsCommonS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18142: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libPluginsCommonS.a
>
>   Line 18150: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\imp\libntg5_browser_audiosource_dsi.a
>
>   Line 18270: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBaseS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18275: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libnpapitraceS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18280: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBaseS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18285: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libnpapitraceS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18290: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBaseS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18295: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libnpapitraceS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18300: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libPluginBaseS.a
>
>   Line 18312: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libnpapitraceS.a
>
>   Line 18328: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBaseMocca.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18340: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBaseMocca.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18345: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBaseMocca.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18354: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libPluginBaseMocca.a
>
>   Line 18452: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBase.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18462: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBase.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18474: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginBase.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18484: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libPluginBase.a
>
>   Line 18538: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUI.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 18543: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUI.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 18555: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUI.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 18571: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libPluginUI.a
>
>   Line 18625: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18630: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18635: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 18651: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libPluginUICairo.a
>
>   Line 20103: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclients.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 20108: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclients.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 20113: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclients.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 20118: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclients.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 20123: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclients.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 20128: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclients.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 20144: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\imp\libdsiclients.a
>
>   Line 21436: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclientsS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21448: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclientsS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21453: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclientsS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21465: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclientsS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21470: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclientsS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21475: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libdsiclientsS.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21487: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\imp\libdsiclientsS.a
>
>   Line 21580: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest_dsi.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21585: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest_dsi.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21594: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 21599: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest_dsi.a_Objects.txt
>
>   Line 21604: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 21613: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 21618: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest_dsi.a
>
>   Line 21639: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\deliveries\libapi_nav_ctrl_NTG5_extdest.a
>
>   Line 21772: HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_ntg5_onlineservices_favoritesmanager.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 21777: HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_ntg5_onlineservices_favoritesmanager.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 21782: HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libapi_ntg5_onlineservices_favoritesmanager.a_Objects.txt 
>   Line 21791: Archive E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\lib\api\libapi_ntg5_onlineservices_favoritesmanager.a
> ```
>
> ---------**

Following is sample log

```
**-----------------------
HBStartArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt 
    PATH=C:\Perl\bin
    perl E:\P4\Onlineservices\buildprocess\tools\perl\util\slashify.pl "CREATE libPluginUICairo.a" >> E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt

HBAddObjectToArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt 
    PATH=C:\Perl\bin
    perl E:\P4\Onlineservices\buildprocess\tools\perl\util\slashify.pl "ADDMOD E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\bin\deliveries\ntg5\intel\api\scp\HBWebkitPluginSDK\PluginBase\PluginUI\Cairo\private\ICairoWidget.o" "ADDMOD E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\bin\deliveries\ntg5\intel\api\scp\HBWebkitPluginSDK\PluginBase\PluginUI\Cairo\private\CCairoContext.o" "ADDMOD E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\bin\deliveries\ntg5\intel\api\scp\HBWebkitPluginSDK\PluginBase\PluginUI\Cairo\private\CColor.o" "ADDMOD E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\bin\deliveries\ntg5\intel\api\scp\HBWebkitPluginSDK\PluginBase\PluginUI\Cairo\private\CProgressBarCairoWidget.o" "ADDMOD E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\bin\deliveries\ntg5\intel\api\scp\HBWebkitPluginSDK\PluginBase\PluginUI\Cairo\private\CScrollCairoWidget.o" "ADDMOD E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\bin\deliveries\ntg5\intel\api\scp\HBWebkitPluginSDK\PluginBase\PluginUI\Cairo\private\CScrollTheme.o" >> E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt

HBFinishArchiverList E:\P4\Onlineservices_products\x86-qnx-m650-4.4.2-osz-trc-rel\tmp\libPluginUICairo.a_Objects.txt 
--------------------------**
```

when I encounter "start" above, I expect "Add" token and then parse subsequent list o f.o files, then when I encounter "finish", I will stop collecting .o files for that archive. In the patterns (3 and 4 ) explain. two or more "start" comes before "add" in the log file, these cases are difficult to parse. please help.

Comment: This is not really a parsing problem. I think you need to keep file-specific state data in your program, not one global state.

Comment: Please post a sample log file that you would like to process.

Comment: Hi Borodin, I have grepped and posted sample logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, this isn't a parsing problem. Parsing the file is equally easy for each of the samples you provided.

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($action, $path) = split(' ', $_, 2);
   ...
}
```

So we're left guessing what you are you trying to do. Is it to group the actions by path?

```
my %actions_by_path;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ($action, $path) = split(' ', $_, 2);
   push @{ $actions_by_path{$path} }, $action;
}
```

Comment: I think yes, when I encounter HBAddObjectToArchiverList, I will again parse its subsequent contents to get list of objects ( log for which is not mentioned in my question), but thats pretty easy. Only thing, is that I need to track "start" and corresponding "Add" then "finish", If I get "start" in between, I need to remember and track its corresponding "Add".

Comment: So I guessed correctly? If so, I'm not sure what you're telling me all this

Comment: Why? All I see is more of what you already had. Are you saying there's a problem with my answer. If so, it would be nice to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Ikegami, I did  not understand following line , -  push @{ $actions_by_path{$path} }, $action;

Comment: Thanks Ikegami, I could understand your code, I can use it to parse futher lines in the log.